# Entity Framework transaction model

Tags: .net, entity-framework, transactions

I would like to know if it is possible to use another transaction system in EF that it is not System.Transaction. Could I use an abstraction of the system.transaction in it?

Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I must admit I'm relatively new to Entity Framework, but I've been doing mega amounts of research recently and have just come across some links on msdn which might help you.

From http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896325.aspx

> When you call SaveChanges, if a current transaction exists, the Entity
>   Framework uses this transaction for operations against the data
>   source. Otherwise, it creates a new transaction for the operation. You
>   can define transactions by using EntityTransaction, Transaction, or
>   TransactionScope.

Taking a look at "EntityTransaction" it inherits from DbTransaction, which in turn implements 
IDbTransaction, IDisposable and inherits MarshalByRefObject. So perhaps you can implement IDbTransaction etc to customise what you require?